# Change backgroundcolor of div when class of list item is hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, background, hover

my website has a horizontal main menu. This menu has a submenu for each menu item. When an item of the submenu is hovered the class of that item gets 'hover' added. When hover is added I want the background color of div (class 'part2') to change.

Site: [europebathroom.com](http://europebathroom.com)

See the code below. In this case I have hovered **item4** and then **subitem2** which gets 'hover' added when you hover the item.

**CODE**

```
<ul class="dj-main">             //main menu
  <li class="item1">...</li>     //main menu items
  <li class="item2">...</li>
  <li class="item3">...</li>
  <li class="item4">

    <div class="submenu">        //dropdown div

      <div class="part1">                       //first half containing submenu
        <ul class="dj-submenu">                 //submenu
          <li class="subitem1">...</li>         //submenu items
          <li class="subitem2 hover">...</li>   //hovered submenu item
        </ul>
      </div>

      // id = part2 added because of the script below
      <div class="part2" id="part2">...</div>     //second half containing color

    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Currently div class = part2 has no backgroundcolor. When hovering subitem2 (when its class = subitem2 hover) the background color must change. I've tried the script below.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('ul.dj-submenu li').each(function(){
    if $(this).hasClass('subitem2 hover'){
        document.getElementById('part2').style.backgroundColor = '#a5a5a5';
    }
});
```

Comment: You can just do this with CSS!

Comment: The div 'part2' is not related to the submenu ul li. How can I change backgroundcolor of 'part2' by hovering li 'subitem2 hover' in CSS then?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

Having re-read your question, I've adjusted the code a bit. Try this

```
$('.subitem2').hover(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('hover')){
        $('.part2').css('background-color','#a5a5a5');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with css only :

```
ul.dj-submenu >li:hover {
   background:#a5a5a5;
}
```

Comment: I want 'part2' of the dropdown div (submenu) to change, not the backgroundcolor of the ul =(

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

HTML:

```
<ul class="dj-main">             //main menu
  <li class="item1">...</li>     //main menu items
  <li class="item2">...</li>
  <li class="item3">...</li>
  <li class="item4">

    <div class="submenu">        //dropdown div

      <div class="part1">                       //first half containing submenu
        <ul class="dj-submenu">                 //submenu
          <li class="subitem1" data-id="1">...</li>         //submenu items
          <li class="subitem2 hover" data-id="2">...</li>   //hovered submenu item
        </ul>
      </div>

      // id = part2 added because of the script below
      <div class="part2" id="part2">...</div>     //second half containing color

    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$('ul.dj-submenu li').each(function(){
var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass('hover')) {
        $('#part' + $this.data('id')).css('background-color','#a5a5a5');
    }
});
```

Should do the trick and works with all menu items. If the color is not dynamic i would prefer a pure CSS solution.